# Power Query M - return most recent column value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, powerquery, m

O365

I'm using PQ to ETL a dataset into Excel.

| ID | Status | Date | CurrentStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Active | 1/1/2022 | Terminated |
| 1 | Terminated | 1/10/2022 | Terminated |

Under CurrentStatus, lookup the row's ID and find the record with the latest Date for that ID then return the Status for that record.

**Current setup:**

Formula is attached to the output table.

Current formula `=XLOOKUP([@ID]&MAXIFS([Date],[ID],[@ID]),[ID]&[Date],[Status],"")`

**Problem:**

Calculation takes forever

**Goal:**

Build the solution into the PQ M code instead of the formula.

Any guidance is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In powerquery, you can group on ID, and within that, sort on date then take the most recent result. Then expand the status

Load the data into powerquery with data from table/range, right click the ID column and Group by

take the default code

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(_), Int64.Type}})
```

and replace the end to resemble this:

```
= Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"data", each _, type table },     {"MaxStatus", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),1)[Status]{0}}})
```

then use the arrow atop the new column to [x] expand the Status, Date and CurrentStatus columns

Full code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Status", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"CurrentStatus", type text}}),
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {{"data", each _, type table },     {"MaxStatus", each Table.FirstN(Table.Sort(_,{{"Date", Order.Descending}}),1)[Status]{0}}}),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "data", {"Status", "Date", "CurrentStatus"}, {"Status", "Date", "CurrentStatus"})
in #"Expanded data"
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, not exactly what I'm looking for. I need to maintain every record on the PQ output with the goal of just adding the CurrentStatus column at the end. It should look like your blue table in the result.

Comment: updated code per feedback

Comment: I just got around to it, and it works! Thanks a ton @horseyride much appreciated. I will add this to my toolbox.